# How to find positive area only between two curves in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the positive area only between two curves, as in where one is higher and only there. The curves are a time series and a horizontal line. This is a picture of the plot it creates: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrPH4.png. I don't want the area where the horizontal line is higher so I can't just find the area under the curve of their difference. I tried using the threshold argument in the auc function:

`auc((1:96), STLFMondayBlock1$mean[(1:96)], thresh = 11648.93)` but I got a value higher with the threshold than without: 1035514 without threshold and 1213062 with a threshold.

Comment: can an area be negative?

Comment: Please provide the time series data.

Comment: @edouard: It can in calculus

Comment: In calculus, area can only be stated as positive while definite integrale can be stated as positive or negative AFAIK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simplified example:

```
x1 <- c(0, 0, rep(1, 4), rep(0, 4), rep(1, 4), 0, 0, 0)
x2 <- rep(0.5, length(x1))
d <- x1 - x2

a <- cumsum(ifelse(d > 0, d, 0))
tail(a, 1)
# 4

par(mar=c(2, 2, 1, 1))
matplot(cbind(x1, x2, a), type="s", lwd=2, col=1:3)
legend("topleft", legend="positive area between curves",
  col=3, lty=3, lwd=2, bty="n")
```

[image]
As you can see, if you take the difference between the two curves and sum only the positive values, you get the total positive area between the two curves.